# Bootstrap: changes to the basic code not shown on web browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and when I copy paste the basic code from the bootstrap site and run it runs perfectly and shows "Hello, World " but when I made an smallest change like "hello world" to "world" it still shows "hello world " Following is the code

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
       
       <head>
          <meta charset = "utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
          <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
          
          <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
          
          <!-- Bootstrap -->
          <link href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
          
          <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
          <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
          
          <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src = "https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src = "https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
          <![endif]-->
          
       </head>
       
       <body>
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          
          <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
          <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          
          <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
          <script src = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If its string not changing then the page must be cached Press ctrl + f5 to clear cache

Comment: Not working @GhanshyamSingh

Answer (score 1):

No problem found.. working perfectly..

**printing hello. world**

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
       
       <head>
          <meta charset = "utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
          <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
          
          <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
          
          <!-- Bootstrap -->
          <link href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
          
          <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
          <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
          
          <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src = "https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src = "https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
          <![endif]-->
          
       </head>
       
       <body>
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          
          <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
          <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          
          <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
          <script src = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
       </body>
    </html>
```

**printing world**

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
       
       <head>
          <meta charset = "utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
          <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
          
          <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
          
          <!-- Bootstrap -->
          <link href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
          
          <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
          <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
          
          <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src = "https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src = "https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
          <![endif]-->
          
       </head>
       
       <body>
          <h1>world!</h1>
          
          <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
          <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          
          <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
          <script src = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
       </body>
    </html>
```

you are not saving the file properly.
when you are trying to print only world..try to change the name of the file and run it.

another thing is possible your browser is caching the file clear the cache.

you have no problem in your code.

Comment: When I save file with other name and run it , it runs perfectly but here is my question why this happened ? When I want to change anything so I should  save  file with other name ? :|

Comment: because your browser is caching the file with previous name and loading it from the cache...clear the cache of your browser...try to run it from other browser you will see that it will work perfectly.

Comment: use this in the head tag `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />`..your browser will stop caching try.